# Get visible text in CSS3 columns

Tags: javascript, css

Trying to make a method which can read the current visible text inside of a element. The method you see below is as far as i've gotten the past few days.

Is there anything more reliable for getting the visible text in a element other than using a caret/range? Cause the issue I'm having is that i have a lot of overflown text who then also gets selected because caret doesn't catch the textNode but instead the parent container.

An example of what my page looks like & why I'm having issues with current method:

[image]

- As of now Gael has the most performance friendly solution & easiest to implement.

Not sure I'm making sense here, otherwise let me know :)

```
function getTextInColumn (rect) {
      var startX = rect.left;
      var startY = rect.top;
      var endX = rect.left + rect.width - 2;
      var endY = rect.top + rect.height - 2;
      var start, end, range = null;
      var i = 0;
      var rangeText = '';

      while ((rangeText === '' && i < 100 && endY > 5)) {
        range = null;

        if (typeof document.caretPositionFromPoint != 'undefined') {
          start = document.caretPositionFromPoint(startX, startY);
          end = document.caretPositionFromPoint(endX, endY);

          if (start !== null && end !== null) {
            range = document.createRange();
            range.setStart(start.offsetNode, start.offset);
            range.setEnd(end.offsetNode, end.offset);
          }
        }
        else if (typeof document.caretRangeFromPoint != 'undefined') {
          start = document.caretRangeFromPoint(startX, startY);
          end = document.caretRangeFromPoint(endX, endY);

          if (start !== null && end !== null) {
            range = document.createRange();
            range.setStart(start.startContainer, start.startOffset);
            range.setEnd(end.startContainer, end.startOffset);
          }
        }

        if (range !== null) {
          rangeText = range.toString();
        }

        endY -= 52;
        i++;
      }

      return rangeText;
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure to understand: you want to grab all the text which is inside the visible part of your page?

Comment: @Gael - I wan't to grab all visible text inside of the DOM element which is showcased in the image i attached to the post. The tricky thing here is that all of the text is within the same element.

Comment: Can you give us the relevant html?

Comment: Can you check if is it what you want to achieve: http://jsfiddle.net/qwu02uz6/2/

Comment: @Gael - That is exactly what I'm looking for. Only concern with that approach is performance. As i got to index 200+ pages using this solution. I'll give the implementation a shot & get back to you with the result :) Thank you very much for giving such detailed example / approach.

Comment: @CircleB - Gael's approach is exactly what I'm trying to archive.

Comment: @Gael - Tried to implement the code you wrote. It works like a a charm. There is only one issue, it's too slow for large amount of texts. Currently having a responsive text from a book on about 200 pages :/

Comment: Yes performance is a big issue! I'm trying to get a better approach with ranges. Do you mind to hightlight the content? Because DOM modifications are heavy. Do you mind if there is no order warranties on the order of the text extracted?

Comment: The order is important, but highlighting of the text is not needed at all.

Comment: You can make some tests with that code: http://codepen.io/gaelb/pen/QbLBQg. I will write a response later.

Comment: @Gael - Very interesting approach. I'll make some tests tomorrow to see the performance difference. Thank you so much for taking your time helping me :)

Comment: @DannieHansen this must be possible with some clever css and much less javascript

Comment: It is mainly before, when the html is build, which it could be possible to ensure to know what is displayed. For example, by dividing the content into blocks, adjusted to the display.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Globally, you have to test each letter to know if it is visible. 
As a block container can be partially visible, and knowing which parts of its contents is visible implies to test them separatly, up to a letter granularity.
Yet, instead of testing each letter, it is possible to test if a set of letters is visible, and using a [binary search method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm), reduce them just as that is necessary to know whether or not all the contained letters are visible.

**the first approach**

The position, the dimension (eg. the bounding rect) of a textNode is not in its properties.

So, I initially tried to insert textNodes in a block element, but that was causing performance issues, as modifying the DOM implies reflows.

More over, we have to not only determine if a text node is visible, but for all of its letters. So I put each letter in a block element:

```
    var text= textNode.nodeValue;
    var markedText= text.replace(/(.)/g,"<span class='marker'>$1</span>");
    var markedContainer= document.createElement("div");
    markedContainer.innerHTML= markedText;

    textContainer.replaceChild(markedContainer,textNode);
```

For a text which contains only 10000 letters, the processing duration was about 10s.

**the Range Interface**

Using [ranges](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Range) to get the position of a set of letters seems a better approach, as we do not have to break into the DOM tree.

A range is initially defined to contains all the text:

```
  var textNode = textContainer.childNodes[0]; //assumes that there is only one child and that it is a textNode

  var range = document.createRange();
  range.selectNodeContents(textNode);
```

then, as `range` has the same [getBoundingClientRect](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Range/getBoundingClientRect) methods as a block container, we can test if there is an intersection with the window bounds:

```
function intersectionArea(a, b) {
  //credits to http://math.stackexchange.com/a/99576
  var x_overlap = Math.max(0, Math.min(a.right, b.right) 
                           - Math.max(a.left, b.left))
  var y_overlap = Math.max(0, Math.min(a.bottom, b.bottom) 
                           - Math.max(a.top, b.top));

  return x_overlap * y_overlap;
}
```

This gives how a range is visible: completly, partially, on none:

```
var intersection = intersectionArea(a, b);
if (intersection == 0) 
  state= "NULL";
else {
  //that means that a is completly in b  
  if (intersection == intersectionArea(a, a))
    state= "COMPLETE";
  else
    state= "PARTIAL";
}
```

If a range is partially visible, it is splitted in two subsets, which will be then tested, up to obtain subsets which are visible or not, but not partially.

```
 /*
     ranges are indexed in an object by their startOffset property
  */
  var ranges = { 0 : range };

  /*
     rangesIdx contains all the ranges which have to be tested
  */
  var rangesIdx = [0];

  while ( rangesIdx.length > 0 ) {

    var range = ranges[ rangesIdx.shift() ];

    switch (overlapsVisibleContent(range)){

      case "PARTIAL":
        // if a range is partially visible, it is splitted on its middle
        // the two resulting ranges will then be tested
        if (range.endOffset - range.startOffset > 1){
          //even if one letter is not completly visible, it is considered to be completly.
          var rangeLastPart= splitRange(range);                
          ranges[ rangeLastPart.startOffset ] = rangeLastPart;

          rangesIdx.push( rangeLastPart.startOffset );
          rangesIdx.push( range.startOffset );
        }else
                if( paintingMode ) 
                paint( range.getBoundingClientRect(), "COMPLETE" )
        break;
      case "COMPLETE":    
        // if a range is completly visible, it stays on the ranges object
        break;
      case "NULL":
        // if a range is completly unvisible, it is deleted from the ranges object.
        delete ranges[ range.startOffset ];
    }
  }
```

With the same text, the processing duration is in the order of tens ms. 
And the complexity does not particularly grow with the text length.

The complete code is [here](http://codepen.io/gaelb/pen/mJdbgv?editors=001)

**some caveats**

It just get visible text of one textNode, but the same logic of binary search could be applied to a DOM tree.

All visible ranges are merged at the end of the process; that could be an issue, as not adjacent lines could be concatenated.

Comment: Awesome approach @Gael - I'll rewrite what I've got so far to use your method & see how it works out. But as the example shows .. it's percet

Comment: It was for me an interesting subject ;)

Comment: Tweaked it so it works with HTML content & so developer can send the test rectangle to the method. http://jsfiddle.net/mnfyqjpv/2/ - that is atleast what i ended up using :) Your solution works alot better than my previous. It's alot quicker too

Comment: I like the TreeWalker :)

Answer (score 0):

As I guess here, you are trying to parse the DOM and get all the elements text 
If you look at the following :
[jQuery.parseHTML()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.parsehtml/)

and look at the DOM element properties 
[DOM Element](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_all.asp)

Look at the example to retrieve the text value 
[DOM element tetxt value](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_node_nodevalue)

If you post your html code, you will get better help

Hope this may help