# Get visible-to-user selected text using Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, security

I'm trying to get selected text in an HTML page using javascript.
`window.getSelection().toString()` works fine for all cases but one.

Suppose to have the following snippet in a HTML page:

```html
Please copy the following text into your terminal to checkout my newest open source project:

<code>
  git clone
  <span style="position: absolute; left: -100px; top: -100px"> /dev/null; some-evil-commands; <br/>git clone </span>
    https://github.com/some-user/some-repository
</code>
```

Due to `position: absolute; left: -100px; top: -100px` the `span` tag containing evil bash commands is not visible to the user, but still selected if him/her select the visible text.

Now, `window.getSelection().toString()` results in

```
git clone /dev/null; some-evil-commands; git clone https://github.com/some-user/some-repository
```

I need to know if there is a way that let me get only the **selected text visible to user**; in this case I need just

```
git clone https://github.com/some-user/some-repository
```

---

*N.B: It is ok to use jQuery too*

Comment: try use something like `$("span").html("").html($("span").html().split("<br>")[1])`

Comment: I do not need a solution for the mentioned page, but for all the cases where there is some hidden text

Comment: how do you suppect that the code will know its "hidden"

Comment: If the user select a text and the selection results in something the user didn't see then there is some hidden text

Comment: I'm not sure we can help you based on the information and code you have shown.

Comment: I'm trying to select only the text which is visible to user, removing all the hidden ones.

Just ask for any kind of additional information do you need and I will edit the question properly

Comment: Take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29773746/5764553)

Comment: It seems to be an interesting approach to a very similar problem.
After a bit of hacks it should solve my problem too. 
Thank you for the reference!

Answer (score -1):

Try using

```
<span style="color:rgba(0,0,0,0);font-size:0.5px;">
```

Hope it helps. Please note: if your bash commands are "evil", please do not deceive people into doing something they do not want.

Comment: Please, read the question. I do not want to know how to make span visible, but how to select in javascript only the text user has selected and is visible to him/her

Comment: so you want the whole thing to be selected, but it to only show the user the clone part?

Comment: When the user load the page he/she see just the "git clone https://..." part, so if the user select he/she is expected to get from the selection just the part he/she see, hidden part excluded.
I want to get using js the selected text that is visible to user, removing the hidden part no matter the way it was hidden